# Is this Auth Flow secure?

Tags: api, security, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm designing an API. It's meant to be consumed by just made-by-us SPAs.

However, I've been two days reading about how I should be implementing Oauth2.0's authorization code flow. And It seems like it's meant to be used in scenarios where you want to give third party clients access to some user resources.

I'm not interested in that.

Is this flow good enough for my purposes?

1. Client (SPA) makes a request to /login with user credentials in the body.
2. Server responds with a JWT Token if the credentials are correct.
3. Client (SPA) stores in localstorage the token and from now on it includes the 
   token in the Authorization header.

The more I read about it, the more lost I am.

Comment: Only you can tell whether this is good enough for your purposes. This is a fairly usual flow. In OAuth terms, this is called resource owner password flow, if you want a standard solution. :) In an SPA it's almost certain you don't want the authorization code flow, because the SPA can't hold a client secret. The other that would be suitable is the implicit flow, but for your usecase that appears too complex with features you don't seem to need.

Answer (score 1):

If the API is a backend for your SPAs, the easiest way is to use the Auth Code Flow with your backend as an OAuth2 client. The backend initiates the auth request, receives an auth code, exchanges it for tokens. Then the backend can create a session with all authentication and authorization info available. The SPA would get a cookie identifying the session. There is a good document [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-04) - which describes best practices.

If you need a stateless backend, you can use the Auth Code Flow in your SPAs. You just use [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) instead of a client secret. Then you can use an access token as an authorization for your API. Refreshing the access token can be done either by using refresh tokens or by an auth request with `&prompt=none`. For more info, see [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/oauth2-implicit-grant-and-spa/#Using-the-Authorization-Code-Grant-from-JavaScript).

If you create your own `/login` endpoint accepting user credentials and verifying them against your OAuth2 server, you lose some benefits - your applications (SPAs and the backend) will work with sensitive data (credentials) which can be a security problem. And you will not be able to use Single Sign On (SSO) feature of the OAuth2 server.

Comment: What security concerns should I have with a much simpler approach as the one I proposed?

Comment: You would have to create a login form which sends user credentials to the backend which processes them somehow. This way, there are more possibilities for an attacker to steal the credentials if there is a bug in your applications. And users usually trust OAuth2 providers more than individual apps that use these providers. So they will not be happy to give your application their credentials (for the OAuth2 provider).

Comment: This solution would bring a lot of complexity (and room for vulnerabilities, ie.attack surface) with zero benefit, because the asker doesn't need the features this would provide. The asker already has the users' credentials, whether they enter it in the spa or a separate component also owned by the asker doesn't matter.

Comment: The question is tagged as OAuth2 and it's not clear whether user credentials are already available to the backend. I think it's more secure to use a standardized protocol and libs than implementing your own. Especially if it uses localStorage (readable by JavaScript and survives browser restarts) and tokens with infinite validity (if it's stolen, the attacker is free to use it).

Comment: Gabor Lengyel you are wrong about this. If you use google authetication or facebook authentication on your page you cannot get user credentials. If you ask user to enter google credentials on your page it is big security issue.

Comment: Yes of course, but the asker said its their own spa consuming their own api. It's clearly stated there is no interest in third party access of any kind. He definitely does not need the authotization code flow.

Comment: I have SPA and my own api and I use authorization code flow to get access token. In every call from my SPA I include access token in the header and on the backend (api) I use token for authorization. Why do you think that is not a good practice?

Comment: You can read about that here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-04#section-5